# Why does the closing lemma follow from the local closing lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a closed smooth manifold. The $C^r$-closing lemma (open in the case $r >1$) says that if $x$ is a non-wandering point of $f \in \mathcal{Diff}^r(M)$ then there is a $g$ arbitrarily $C^r$ close to $f$ for which $x$ is periodic.

The local $C^r$ closing lemma states that under the same hypothesis as above, for any neighborhood $U$ of $f$ in $\mathcal{Diff}^r(M)$ and neighborhood $V$ of $x$, there is a $g \in U$ and $x_g \in V$ such that $x_g$ is periodic for $g$.

It's claimed in the 2012 survey article of D. V. Anosov and E. V. Zhuzhoma that the local closing lemma implies the closing lemma, by an argument from Pugh. The proof given in [1], for vector fields, but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Does anyone know of a proof for diffeomorphisms? Thanks in advance.

[1] Pugh, Charles C. "The Closing Lemma." American Journal of Mathematics 89, no. 4 (1967)

Comment: Anosov and Zhuzhoma explained the argument in page 1657 of the paper, the paragraph right under the statement of the $C^r$-closing lemma. The argument is clear there. It is worth saying that those $C^r$ closing lemmas are statements only. For $r$ different than $0$ and $1$ there are no general theorems that says that $C^r$-closing lemmas hold.